# Convert List<String> of uuids to player names spigot java

Tags: java, minecraft

I have a List in my main class that gets data from a certain section in config. Here's the code for it,

```
private List<String> datalist;

public List<String> getDataList() {
    if (datalist == null) {
        datalist = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    datalist = datalist.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    return datalist;
}
void loadConfig() {
    final FileConfiguration config = this.getConfig();
    config.options().copyDefaults(true);
    saveConfig();

    ConfigurationSection section = this.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("data");
    if (section != null) {
        Set<String> datas = section.getKeys(false);
        if (datas != null && !datas.isEmpty()) {
            for (String data : datas) {
                getDataList().add(data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

loadConfig() get's called in the onEnable method. Currently, if I sent this to a player or console, it would be formatted in an arraylist. ([uuid,uuid,uuid,etc,etc]). My config is formatted like this,

```
data:
  e81a48c8-6e82-304a-b435-832a362b4cbf:
    name: PiggyPiglet
    stat1: 0
    stat2: 0
    stat3: 0
    hasjoined: true
```

One of these getting generated for a player on PlayerJoinEvent. I have a command, /lb show in my commands class, here's the code for it.

```
if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("show")) {
                    if (sender.hasPermission("leaderboard.show")) {
                        sender.sendMessage(cc("&7LeaderBoard:"));

                        String lb = String.valueOf(plugin.getDataList()).replace("[",
                                "").replace("]",
                                "").replace(",",
                                "\n");
                        TextComponent leaderboard = new TextComponent(lb);
                        leaderboard.setHoverEvent( new HoverEvent( HoverEvent.Action.SHOW_TEXT, new ComponentBuilder("test").create() ) );
                        sender.spigot().sendMessage(leaderboard);
                    }
                }
```

That code sends in chat the uuids in config like this.

```
uuid
uuid
uuid
```

And when you hover over one of the uuids, it says "test". My question is how would I change those uuids to player names and also instead saying "test", saying

`"EGCW | EGCL | KWC\n" + String.valueOf(cfg.getInt("data." + uuid + ".EGCW")) + " | " + String.valueOf(cfg.getInt("data." + uuid + ".EGCL")) + " | " + String.valueOf(cfg.getInt("data." + uuid + ".KWC"))"`

Replacing uuid with the uuid on the current line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your UUIDs are another `ConfigSection` as child of `data`, so you need to go one level deeper.

This approach might not be the best, but it works.

```
ConfigurationSection section = config.getConfigurationSection("data");
        if (section != null) {
            Set<String> datas = section.getKeys(false);
            if (datas != null && !datas.isEmpty()) {
                for (String uuid : datas) {
                    ConfigurationSection section2 = config.getConfigurationSection("data." + uuid);
                    if (section2 != null) {

                    getDataList().add(section2.getString("name"));

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(datalist);
```

Output from using a slightly altered `config.yml` (it's better to have more than one user in it):
`[PiggyPiglet1, PiggyPiglet2, PiggyPiglet3]`

The `ComponentBuilder` should then work as intended. Just replace "test" with the String you want to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of `PlayerService` that gives you the method `findByUuid(String uuid)` and returns you a `Player`.

Once you have it, you can convert your list of `String` into a list of names like this :

```
datalist.stream().map(uuid -> playerService.findByUuid(uuid))
    .filter(player -> player != null)
    .map(player -> player.getName()) 
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

But in your case, you'd better retrieve the `Map<String,Player>` from the config rather than just the keys. Then, no need from the service, you would just have to perform a `get(uuid)` on the map.